# Xamarin Android Contextual ActionMode Bar on appcompat-v7 Toolbar not dismissed when button pressed on API 21

Tags: xamarin.android

I have encountered the following weird bug on my Android Xamarin project.

I have an EditText field that makes use of the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar on an AppCompatActivity class, I have set the project minimum API to target the API 15. Currently I'm using the AppCompat-v7 25.1.1.

The app shows the Contextual ActionMode Bar on long press on an EditText normally on Android API<21 and >22 but for some weird reason API 21 and 22 the action bar is not dismissed completely.

The icons can be seen on the toolbar and they are not clickable. If the drawer is opened, then the toolbar comes back to normal.

[Contextual ActionMode Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnV2K.png)

[Action Bar back button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtjUu.png).

This is my Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Base.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/Purple</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/CustomPurpleDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/Blue</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

In the class I have

```
_toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.Toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
_toolbar.StartActionMode(this); //I have added this so I can listen to the ActionMode.ICallback interface methods
```

I have also added

```
    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.home)
        {
            mode.Finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        _actionMode = mode;
        return true;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        _actionMode.Finish();
        _actionMode = null;
    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.